# mysqladmin ping error code

Tags: mysql, linux, mysqladmin

Mysqladmin ping returns 0 even with a password failure, a thing that mysqlclient doesn't. Is this a mistake from Mysqladmin Developpers? I don't understand why Mysqladmin is asking for a login/password because it returns 0 even if you don't specify a login.

If I try a Mysqladmin ping without any login/password :

```
# mysqladmin ping ; echo $?

mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
0
```

Mysqladmin give me a login error and tells me that the server is currently running (0 value) so why asking for a login if it still gives me the answer?

When I do something like this :

```
#mysqladmin -uroot -pWrongPassword ping ; echo $?

mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'
0
```

This return me 0 instead of 1.

Now if I stop mysql server and try again :

```
# mysqladmin -uroot -pWrongPassword ping ; echo $?

mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
1
```

It gives me the proper value because the server is stopped, we dont care about the wrong password.

Finally i did the same test with Mysqlclient and a wrongpassword :

```
# mysql -uroot -pWrongPassword mysql -sN -e "select * from user" ; echo $?

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
1
```

I know that the main purpose of this command is to test the availability of the mysql server but ask for a login/password doesn't make any sense if you still give the 0 value.

Do you think it is a bug?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not a bug. This behavior is by design.

> **[ping](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqladmin.html)**
>   Check whether the server is available. The return status from
>   mysqladmin is 0 if the server is running, 1 if it is not. This is 0
>   **even in case of an error such as Access denied, because this means
>   that the server is running but refused the connection**, which is
>   different from the server not running.

Comment: You can use `status` though!