# MariaDB Access denied for user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: NO) while docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I'm working on Debian-based Virtual Box

I have docker-compose yaml file:

```yaml
version: '3' 
services:
  mydb:
    build: ./db/
    restart: always 
    networks:
      - dockercompose-frontend 
    volumes:
      - server_db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mariadb-admin", "ping", "-h", "localhost", "--protocol=tcp"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 15s
      retries: 5
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  frontend:
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - dockercompose-frontend
    environment:
      PMA_HOST=mydb
      PMA_ARBITRARY=1
      PMA_PORT=3306
    depends_on:
      - mydb
     

volumes:
  server_db:
    driver: local
networks:
  dockercompose-frontend:
    driver: bridge
```

And two Dockerfiles for each of the services, where I just install necessary images.

```
FROM mariabd:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y iputils-ping
```

and

```
FROM phpmyadmin:5.2.0-apache
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y iputils-ping
```

When I'm using `docker compose up -d` and checks Health State for mydb it throws:

```
{
  "Status":"healthy", 
  "FailingStreak": 0, 
  "Log": [{"Start": "2024-02-19T10:05:48.178379963-05:00",
    "End": 2024-02-19T10:05:48.240662846-05:00", 
    "ExitCode": 0, 
    "Output":"mariadb-admin: Access denied for user root@127.0.0.1 (using password: NO)"
}
```

Also,

```
docker exec dockercompose-mydb-1 service mariadb status
```

throws "Access denied for user root@127.0.0.1 (using password: NO)"

After

```
docker exec dockercompose-mydb-1 service mariadb restart
docker exec dockercompose-mydb-1 service mariadb status
```

it throws the same

Comment: for maria db the env should be `MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD` and not `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb)

Comment: @AshutoshPatole
1) Unfortunatelly, it doesn't help
2) In phpmyadmin documentation says, that `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` also valid
[link](https://hub.docker.com/r/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/) here

Comment: @danblack Unfortunatelly, no

Comment: Use `healthcheck.sh` rather than playing with over/under privileged `mariadb-admin` commands.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the password to the healthcheck call with "-proot" to not get the warning:

```
      test: ["CMD", "mariadb-admin", "-proot", "ping", "-h", "localhost", "--protocol=tcp"]
```

Similar issue here: [mysqladmin ping error code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522847/mysqladmin-ping-error-code)

Minimal example using your Dockerfile for the build:

```
version: '3' 
services:
  mydb:
    build: ./db/
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mariadb-admin", "-proot", "ping", "-h", "localhost", "--protocol=tcp"]
```

Comment: Now I get `Access denied for user root@127.0.0.1 (using password: YES)` (was NO)

Comment: Are you sure the root password is working? If this does not work `docker exec -it [id-of-the-running-container] mariadb -proot`, then your password is not `root`.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure if it works. After `docker exec -it [id-of-the-running-container] mariadb -proot` I'v got the same err :(

Comment: Checked ur link with simillar issue. Do you think it's works normally? I though it has to give some "pretty" response like nginx. It's first time I'm working with MySQL, even databases, and I could have some "unclear" vision on that.

Comment: Most likely then your root password is set to something else beforehand, and MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD will not overwrite it in subsequent runs. If your volume does not contain some important data already, delete it and let the container recreate it from scratch, and the root password should be "root" afterwards.

Comment: I did `docker volume prune`. After `up` I get `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket`. **BUT** on the second `up` I'v got `Access denied for user root@127.0.0.1 (using password: YES)`.